# How to create a rule or VBA code for Outlook to copy the the messages from specific folder to another folder?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am looking solution to the following **problem:**

There is a mailbox for the requests from the customers with 7 clients that filtering the incoming e-mail from general "Inbox" to the different folders manually.

Let's say to the folders `A`, `B` and `C` with regard to the relevance of request. After that, the employees process the letter and move them to folder `X` or delete them.

***I need to find***: the number of e-mails that were ever moved to the folder `A` for the reporting purposes. Not the actual one but the historical.

**My idea:** as far as I am looking for the solution that is relatively easy to implement I thought somehow to make a rule or VBA code to copy every letter that comes to the folder `A` to the new order `X` or alternatively to another mailbox.

Would very happy to hear the ideas of others or suggestion how to implement my idea.